# MultiBit HD and exporting private keys

Tags: client, private-key, multibit-hd, private-key-export

Before I wrote here I was read this post: 
[How can you extract private keys from MultiBit HD?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/40507/how-can-you-extract-private-keys-from-multibit-hd) and few others.

I know from above thread that it is hard to extract private keys from MultiBit HD wallet, however it can be done other way or using different application. I was looking for it in internet, but it is hard to find anything. Could you tell me or provide link to know how to do that?