# Bitcoin Cash Multibit HD/Electrum

Tags: transactions, private-key, multibit, electrum, bitcoin-cash

If I had my BTC in a multibit HD wallet prior to the fork, and I exported my wallet to Electrum after the fork, will the BCH still be tied to the multibit HD wallet?

And if so, how can I access the BCH stored in the multibit HD wallet?

Answer (score 4):

Here is what you need to do. Make sure you have the seed from multibit.

1. Download http://www.electroncash.org/
2. You create a new wallet, select I already have seed, when you type seed you need to click the "options" button and select **BIP39 seed**.
3. It will ask for a derivation path... you need to use: m/0' (note the ' it is important... m/0')
   4.Suggest you do research as there are some issues with it not connecting to BCC chain sometimes.

http://reddit.com/r/btc/comments/6qyn18/electroncash_notice_how_to_select_bitcoincash/

Comment: Ah I'll give it a try when I get back from work!

Comment: Hi, I used this method and it works. The problem is that I did not export my multibit HD wallet before doing this process, and now I can not access to my multibit HD wallet, not even can recover with my seed. What happens? How can I get my Bitcoins back?

Comment: You should be able to access your BTC using electrum wallet https://electrum.org Use the seed from multibit HD.

Comment: The default derivation seems `m/44'/145'/0'` so I will change it to `m/0'`

Answer (score 0):

If you have exported your Multibit HD wallet into Electrum, then your Electrum wallet is sharing the Private Keys with your Multibit wallet. In a less technical language: You have one account (your wallet) and 2 interfaces to access your funds (Multibit and Electrum).

The BCH are tied to your account not the interface. So forget about Multibit and redeem your bitcoin cash with the help of Electrum. Follow the official Electrum [Recommendation on how to redeem Bitcoin Cash](https://electrum.org/bcc2.txt). Short version below:

1. Secure your bitcoin funds by withdrawing them to another bitcoin
   wallet.
2. Export your seed or private key from Electrum.
3. Install Electron Cash.
4. Import your MB seed into Electron Cash.
5. Enjoy your coins.

Answer (score 0):

**If you do not have your seed**, extracting your bitcoin cash without your wallet words works, but requires knowing how to edit and compile java code: https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/51297/64842

Because installing maven, java, modifying and compiling the JAR, and using the private keys is a bit beyond most non-developers, I've created a comprehensive guide, along with a pre-built JAR file to walk you through it:

https://github.com/josephduchesne/multibit-hd/blob/develop/README.md

The summary is:

1. Get a patched version of MultiBit-HD based on redee's answer linked above
2. Get your wallet addresses
3. Extract your private keys
4. Import into electron