# How to claim BCC/BCH having BTC in MultibitHD without having a seed, but having a password?

Tags: multibit-hd, bitcoin-cash

I wanted to add a comment [here](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/57482/bitcoin-cash-multibit-hd-electrum), but I do not have enough reputation, so please forgive me.

So I am using MultibitHD wallet. I have access to my bitcoins after I type my password. I can send then to new address, so I think this mean, that I have there my private keys.

However I discover that I do not have saved those 12 words from seed in place where I thought I saved them.

Question is, how can I extract keys and claim BitcoinCash?

Disclaimer: I have there 0.25 BTC. I will give 0.025 BCH to someone who help me discover the solution :)

**I would like to dump my BCH, to support BTC, but first I need to know how to claim them. Please help me support BTC!**

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there is no easy way to do that. MultiBit does not allow you to export private keys and they use their own implementation of AES to encrypt the wallet files so no third party tool (like bitcoinj' wallet tool) can be used to extract the private keys. All you can do is modify the MultiBit source code and run it yourself in order to dump the private keys to a file.

Answer (score 0):

just made it. MultibitHD is not working so you need to transfer it to electum wallet:
1. In Electum create a new wallet, select I already have seed, 
2. Type in your seeds (security words) click option button and select BIP39 seed. 3. It will ask for a derivation path, you need to use: m/0' (note the ' is important m/0')
4. your wallet with your btc should appear

now follow the steps from official electrum to receive bcc
https://electrum.org/bcc.txt

Comment: as I said, I do not have a seed.

Comment: @lenka Without the seed you cannot recover BCH. More importantly multibit is dead, so move them to a better wallet

Comment: This answer got 50% of my coins into electrum. Any idea where the other half are? Presumably they are change address derivations?

Answer (score 0):

Answering regards:
*This answer got 50% of my coins into electrum. Any idea where the other half are? Presumably they are change address derivations?*

It seems they are in the external addresses. Your transactions are split in internal (your local wallet) and external addresses.

More about how to find your external addresses is at [How to sweep private extended key from mycellium into coinomi for bitcoin cash coins?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/57422/how-to-sweep-private-extended-key-from-mycellium-into-coinomi-for-bitcoin-cash-c/)

Answer (score 0):

Extracting your bitcoin cash without your wallet words, as answered here works, but requires knowing how to edit and compile code: https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/51297/64842

Because installing maven, java, modifying and compiling the JAR, and using the private keys is a bit beyond most non-developers, I've created a comprehensive guide, along with a pre-built JAR file to walk you through it:

https://github.com/josephduchesne/multibit-hd/blob/develop/README.md

The summary is:

1. Get a patched version of MultiBit-HD based on redee's answer linked above
2. Get your wallet addresses
3. Extract your private keys
4. Import into electron

Comment: You should expect the linked files to be coin-stealing malware.

Comment: I agree, it's a bad idea to use any bitcoin applications that you haven't verified the signature of or  compiled yourself. That said, for people that are less technical what can they do? If they can't compile the code themselves, there was previously no option to recover their BCC since the author abandoned the wallet. Would you like to audit my 1 line diff, compile the code and post a checksum? Why trust you, my potential puppet account? I'm open to suggestions.