# Claim BCH with Electrum wallet

Tags: electrum, bitcoin-cash

Here are the steps I took:

- I moved my BTC to a new Electrum wallet and waited to get 6 confirmations.
- I copy pasted the seed of the old electrum wallet
- I installed Electron Cash on a new PC
- I created a new wallet there and used the seed of the old electrum wallet

output: 0 BCH

is this because I could have had Multibit HD at the time of the fork? I do not know for sure if I used Electrum back in august 2017...
Or is there an other explanation?

**edit** I think that I found a similar situation here [Bitcoin Cash Multibit HD/Electrum](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/57482/10173) but I am not 100% sure that I had a multibit hd wallet back then or an electrum. But because my electrum seed gave me 0 BCH it probably was multibit hd back then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Where have your BTC been on Aug 1?** That's deciding.

If I understand it correctly, you created a new BTC-wallet and sent your BTC there. But your BCH are still on the adresses on which your BTC have been on Aug 1.

So you need to get the seed of your older wallet (where they have been on Aug 1) or (if you did not use a HD wallet that time) you need to get the private keys of the adresses of the old wallet (almost wallets allow you to export them). You can import them in Electron Cash then.

Comment: It is either in Multibit HD or Electrum. I do not know for sure. Is there a way to verify the balance of a wallet address on that date? If it was in multibit-hd is there a way to get the bch?

Comment: I'm finding it hard to import private keys into electron - Electrum bitcoin exports a huge csv file - and this doesn't import properly - telling me I only need to import keys with balances. Super not clear.

Answer (score 0):

I did it! with this https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/57505/10173

- I found my seed/ wallet words of the old multibit wallet.
- Installed bitcoin cash on a new pc
- select new standard bitcoin cash wallet
- select use seed
- type the wallet words
- click options to select `BIP39 seed`
- derivation path. changed the default `m/44'/145'/0'` to `m/0'`
- made a new password for the bch wallet

and it's done!