# How to recover Bitcoin Cash from Multibit Wallet?

Tags: multibit, bitcoin-cash, private-key-export

I have been reading through posts and cannot figure out if this is possible or not. But I had bitcoin on an old Multibit wallet. I do not have the seed phrase from when I opened the wallet, just the key to the wallet. I have just moved the bitcoin off to a secure wallet. However is there any way to recover the bitcoin cash? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

[Export the private keys from the Multibit wallet](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/40507/how-can-you-extract-private-keys-from-multibit-hd), then import them into a Bitcoin Cash wallet. How to import them will depend on which wallet you choose to use.

Don't use the public addresses associated with those private keys again for Bitcoin transactions (I think you know that already though since you've already shifted your bitcoins away... which is the safe thing to do).