# Moving funds from MultiBit 0.5.18 into new Software (Electrum)

Tags: wallet, electrum, multibit

Since Multibit support has ended I want to move my funds to a new software. As far as I've seen Electrum is recommended for this purpose. I've followed instructions from the answer of Dr.Bob https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/57325/113828 in this question.

Now I've a Electrum 4.0.9 wallet with status [imported] and it displays the correct amount of credits at the bottom of Electrum.

Can I now leave things as they are and I've switched successfully to Electrum? And I can use it for upocming sendings and receivings? I just want to make sure sure that someday my funds won't be inaccessible since Multibits support has ended.

Answer (score 2):

You can use it. Electrum, nowadays, is as popular as Multibit used to be, so you can assume that you will always be able to recover your coins.

To be safer, you can export the private keys from Electrum and save them in an encrypted archive such as ZIP or 7zip. (But you need to do this every time you make a transaction)

What I would actually do would be to create a new wallet in Electrum, but this time, of type HD wallet. Then you can write down just a few words (12 or 18 ?) and be able to physically backup your coins. This would have the advantage of not having to update the backup as all your private keys would be deterministic childs of your master key (=those words)

Comment: Ok thanks. How do I get my coins into the new HD wallet? By normal transfer?

Comment: Yes. Old wallet -> HD requires a transaction.